# How to fix body height for AdminLTE 2.4.0 and turbolinks 5

Tags: javascript, turbolinks, adminlte

I'm trying to setup `AdminLTE` there for my admin app and everything goes well except of content resize after navigating between views.

This happens because `turbolinks` prevents page reload and events like `window.onResize` (or whatever) doesn't called. If I manually resize window, height will be fixed.

I've founded solution here -> https://github.com/almasaeed2010/AdminLTE/issues/563#issuecomment-242715795 , but it doesn't work because `$.AdminLTE is undefined`.

I've looked into `AdminLTE` sources, but unfortunately my javascript skills are not good enough to look up for proper code so I'm wondering what to use instead of `$.AdminLTE`.

Comment: Did you check the comment for `GCorbel  commented on Sep 8 2015 `, the javascript version?

Comment: For sure I've checked, his script uses `$.AdminLTE` and my question is exactly about how to get this `$.AdminLTE`?

Comment: Post the repo and exactly in which file and line are you adding the script please.

Comment: Can't post repo at the moment (it's private), but I've tried to add this script as the last as well as after the body. It doesn't work. Also, I've tried to call this function from js console while been on AdminLTE demo page, it doesn't work either.

Comment: It seems that you need to call it this way `$.fn.layout.Constuctor.prototype.activate()` instead of `$.AdminLTE.layout.activate();`....

Comment: @Hackerman, yep, it does fix the height, but I see error in console:
`Cannot read property 'resetHeight' of undefined`

Comment: `$.fn.layout.Constuctor.prototype.fix()` does the trick.

Comment: I knew it....just for the record on what I did....I look at the live preview of the admin lte site, and check the source code...to this particular file `<script src="dist/js/adminlte.min.js"></script>`...then I use an online javascript beautifier to unminify the code and then I just compare it with the version https://github.com/almasaeed2010/AdminLTE/blob/master/dist/js/adminlte.js ...after a little bit of analyzing the code I was able to get the right piece!!...you own me a beer man xD

Comment: Oh wait, it doesn't returns instance of layout, I'm just calling it as a new object. How to get instance?

Comment: Okay, i'll use it as a temporary fix but will wait for proper solution.

Comment: Hold my beer.....to get the instance you can use this `var $layout  = $('body').data('lte.layout')`...then you can use `$layout.activate()` or `$layout.fix()`...yesss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the answer from project maintainer — https://github.com/almasaeed2010/AdminLTE/issues/1667

```
var ready = function () {
    return $(window).trigger('resize');
};
document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', ready);
```

I believe this should work in the future versions also, when some of code responsible for resizing/fixing layouts will be changed.

Answer (score 0):

To get the current instance of the `layout` plugin, you can use the following snippet:

```
var $layout = $('body').data('lte.layout')
```

Then you can call any of the methods, like:

```
$layout.activate() 
$layout.fix()
```